# How to delete all logs except last 100 for each user in single table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a single logs table which contains entries for users. I want to (prune) delete all but the last 100 for each user. I'd like to do this in the most efficient way (one statement using ActiveRecord if possible).

I know I can use the following:

- `.order(created_at: :desc)` to get the records sorted
- `.offset(100)` to get all records except the ones I want to keep
- `.ids` to pluck the record ids
- `select(:user_id).distinct` to get a list of all users in the table

The table has `id`, `user_id`, `created_at` columns (and others not pertinent to this question).

Each user should have at least the last 100 log entries remaining the logs table.

Not really sure how to do this using ruby syntax with my Log model. If it can't be done efficiently using ruby then I'll resort to using the SQL equivalent.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you could do this:

```
DELETE FROM logs
USING (SELECT id
       FROM (SELECT id,
                    row_number()
                       OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
                             ORDER BY created_at DESC)
                       AS rownr
             FROM logs
            ) AS a
       WHERE rownr > 100
      ) AS b
WHERE logs.id = b.id;
```

If the table is large, this will be slow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't get it to work. I get a syntax error for USING.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `FROM` clause in the inner query.

Comment: I'm still getting the same ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"

Comment: Table is not called logs but I've updated the 3 places it's named and I'm definitely using Postgresql (v11.3). https://github.com/kodemunki/sql/blob/master/Screen%20Shot%202019-06-28%20at%2012.09.24%20am.png